# Mirrioing facebook comments in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-comments, mirroring

Referring to this URL https://developers.facebook.com/products/social-plugins/comments/ , I am searching for possibility of facebook comments mirriong in ios app. After googling, not able to get the proper docs or any links to do it in iOS. Is it possible in ios ? Any help or links will be appreciated. Thanks.